# I want get documents using ObjectId, but it's not getting that document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB and trying to get multiple documents using ObjectId

Below I have mentioned the demo data format.

```
db={
"store": [
{
  "_id": ObjectId("63da2f1f7662144569f78ddd"),
  "name": "bat",
  "price": 56,
  
},
{
  "id": ObjectId("63da2f1f7662144569f78ddc"),
  "name": "ball",
  "price": 58,
  
},
{
  "id": ObjectId("63da2f1f7662144569f78ddb"),
  "name": "cap",
  "price": 100,
  
},
{
  "id": ObjectId("63da2f1f7662144569f78dda"),
  "name": "red",
  "price": 50,
  
},

]}
```

and my query is this

```
db.store.aggregate([
{
$match: {
  id: {
    $in: [
      ObjectId("63da2f1f7662144569f78ddd"),
      ObjectId("63da2f1f7662144569f78ddb"),
      ObjectId("63da2f1f7662144569f78dda")
    ]
  }
}
},
{
$group: {
  _id: null,
  totalPrice: {
    $sum: "$price"
  }
}
},
{
$project: {
  _id: 0,
  
}
}
])
```

and output is

```
[
{
"totalPrice": 150
}
]
```

but I'm getting objectid like this

```
{
  "ids": 
  ["63da2f1f7662144569f78ddd","63da2f1f7662144569f78ddb","63da2f1f7662144569f78dda"]
}
```

if I pass this array it's not getting any documents. How can I pass this array in place of objectids????

Comment: You are passing array of strings, instead of array of ObjectIds. That will match no document.

Comment: where does ids come from? Try to fix your question.

Comment: it's coming from the client side.

Comment: is there any other way to get this? @SuleymanSah

Comment: pass like `id: { $in: ids.map(e => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(e)) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, you can simply wrap the payload from client in a `$map` to convert them into ObjectIds with `$toObjectId`

```js
db.store.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        "$in": [
          "$id",
          {
            "$map": {
              // your payload from client here
              "input": [
                "63da2f1f7662144569f78ddd",
                "63da2f1f7662144569f78ddb",
                "63da2f1f7662144569f78dda"
              ],
              "as": "id",
              "in": {
                "$toObjectId": "$$id"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalPrice: {
        $sum: "$price"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VnAgHiJvxYA)

Comment: Thanks @ray. I have another doubt if there is another store like store1 and store2 and now I'm getting two ID's array one for store1 and the other for store2 and now I need to send them both the total price of all products from store1 and store2. Then how i can achieve that?

Comment: @RajeshSenapati Please update the question with newer sample of data and input array. If the involved change is too large, consider asking a new question and link to this question to provide context